# Populating ASP.Net DetailsView textbox with default value when entering Add mode

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, code-behind, default-value, populate

We would like to populate a textbox with today's date as a default value when the user goes into "Add" mode on an ASP.Net DetailsView from a VB.Net code-behind file. Can you show me how to get it populated?

Here is the markup for the textbox we wish to populate:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Late Time Arrived At School:" SortExpression="LateTimeArrivedAtSchool">

    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxLateTimeArrivedAtSchool" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("LateTimeArrivedAtSchool", "{0:hh:mm}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>

    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxLateTimeArrivedAtSchool" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("LateTimeArrivedAtSchool", "{0:hh:mm}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </InsertItemTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelLateTimeArrivedAtSchool" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("LateTimeArrivedAtSchool", "{0:hh:mm}") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <ItemStyle ForeColor="Blue" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

We also have set up OnItemCommand as shown in this markup:

```
<asp:DetailsView 
    ID="DetailsView" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateRows="False" 
    Height="50px" 
    Width="207px" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDetails"
    DataKeyNames="ID"
    OnItemCommand="DetailsViewDetails_ItemCommand">

    <Fields>
```

The code-behind file has this coding:

```
Protected Sub DetailsViewDetails_ItemCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewCommandEventArgs)

    Select Case e.CommandName

        Case "Add"


        Case "Edit"
            ButtonAddNewAttendance.Enabled = False

        Case "Delete"

        Case "Update"
            ButtonAddNewAttendance.Enabled = True

        Case "Insert"

    End Select
End Sub
```

I tried to type TextBoxLateTimeArrivedAtSchool.Text in the Case -> "Add" but got a message that TextBoxLateTimeArrivedAtSchool was not defined. I'm not sure why intellisence did not find it from the markup.

I was thinking Case -> "Add" was the correct place to populate the textbox but looks like that's not the place to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to find the control first. The code should be something like this:

```
Select Case e.CommandName

    Case "Add"
        Dim txtBox As TextBox
        textBox = DetailsViewDetails.FindControl("TextBoxLateTimeArrivedAtSchool")
        textBox.Text = DateTime.Now
```